# EKS cron job fails to deploy

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, yaml, amazon-eks

I am trying to deploy my first cron job.

Starting with a very simple one, as described in the k8s [tutorial](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/):

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: hello
spec:
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: hello
            image: busybox
            imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
            command:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - date; echo Hello from the Kubernetes cluster
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

I am connected to my EKS cluster. This is the command and output:

```
➜  Dev kubectl apply -f cronjob.yaml                                         
error: unable to recognize "cronjob.yaml": no matches for kind "CronJob" in version "batch/v1"
```

And batch/v1 does exists in my apiVersion list.

Can't understand what is wrong..

Comment: What kubernetes version are you using in your EKS cluster?

Comment: k8s v1.18 is what i use

Comment: In case you want to check the version of any object in your installed environment, use explain command. Eg: `kubectl explain cronjob|grep VERSION`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Cronjob apiVersion in the kubernetes 1.18 is `batch/v1beta1`

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: hello
spec:
  schedule: "*/1 * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: hello
            image: busybox
            args:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - date; echo Hello from the Kubernetes cluster
```

[Source](https://v1-18.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/#creating-a-cron-job)

Comment: Yes! thanks a lot! can you please take a look on this thread as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67470919/yaml-file-cannot-lint